# Is it possible to get dark elixir before Town Hall 7?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Is it possible to get dark elixir before Town Hall 7? Is there any way to store it without having a dark elixir storage?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to store Dark Elixir without a Dark Elixir Storage, so no, it is not possible to get Dark Elixir before Town Hall 7.  Appropriately, there is nothing you can ***spend*** Dark Elixir on before Town Hall 7 anyway.

Comment: It is possible to store Dark Elixir without a Dark Elixir Storage I believe. A level 7 Town Hall has internal storage for Dark Elixir, but that said its a level 7 Town Hall, which isn't available until you reach Town Hall 7. :P

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you could get attacked by someone using dark elixir troops, and then not collect those headstones until you get to TH 7, but that would require extreme patience and willpower, so unless you have that, then no.

Answer (score 0):

You could attack a base with dark elixir and steal it but without storage and dark barrack, it is useless. Also the chance of stealing is almost impossible as dark elixir is well protected.

Answer (score 0):

**NO.**

When you attack a base and get Dark Elixir from it as a TH6 and below, the verdict (victory/defeat) screen will show you the amount of Dark Elixir you have stolen but since you have no storages as this can be only obtained starting at Town Hall Level 7, it simply disappears, just like when your other resource storages are full.